# Why do they call it "inside_access_in"?

Tags: cisco, cisco-pix

I am looking at some configurations for Cisco FWSM devices and I notice a common notation for an ACL name called `inside_access_in`. But I am commonly seeing ACEs that are for allowing internal machines to access specific resources on the "outside".

My question is this: Why do they call it `inside_access_in`? Why not call it `inside_access_out`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ACL you're talking about is typically applied to traffic coming *into* the interface named "inside". The ACL is used to limit traffc that's *bound for* the "outside", but often it's applied with the command:

```
access-group inside_access_in in interface inside
```

So, you're limiting outbound access by limiting the traffic that can come into the firewall from the machines attempting to access the outside!  >smile<

Answer (score 2):

Because it's the name of the interface "inside" that you're pointing at.  In other words you're going "in" to the inside interface.